# Error in another compute installation in Openstack cloud

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron, openstack-horizon, openstack-heat

I have installed openstack cloud with packstack. Now I'm trying to add another compute to my cloud. I got an error while installing a compute.

> CONFIG_NEUTRON_L2_AGENT: You have choosen OVN neutron backend. Note that this backend does not s upport LBaaS, VPNaaS or FWaaS services. Geneve will be used as encapsulation method for tenant networks

Comment: That looks like a warning rather than an error. Those things are all true, but your cloud should operate just fine. Are things functioning as expected or not?

Comment: Thank you...I'll check that...